# How to call a C# class library from a Classic ASP web site on Azure Web Services?

Tags: c#, azure, asp-classic, com-interop

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution with 2 projects:

- A classic ASP web site.
- A C# class library.

How do I call the C# methods from within the classic ASP pages?

I will deploy the solution to Azure App Services.

I do know that I could create a web API and call it that way. But I am wondering if there is any other way to do this.

UPDATE:

I made the C# class "COM-Visible" and checked the “Register for COM interop” option, and everything works correctly on my development machine.

But when I publish the solution to Azure Web Services, it doesn't work. The Classic ASP page runs fine, but I get this error when trying to create the object:

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
Server.CreateObject Failed
/index.asp, line 34
800401f3
```

It seems “Register for COM interop” doesn’t work in Azure App Services. I know I could create a VM and register the dll manually, but I would prefer to use Azure App Services instead.

Comment: Why no Server.CreateObject?  Make the assembly COM Visible then Server.CreateObject.

Comment: Another option to consider, if unable to just replace your classic ASP site with something a bit more modern, would be to look at how it's already accessing the data layer.  If linking to a .Net library would only serve as a way to do simple CRUD from a database, it may be better to make calls from the page to the database's stored procedures.

Comment: I though Server.CreateObject could not be used in an Azure Web App. I will try making the COM visible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the two methods you mentioned - Web API (or similar intermediary service) and `Server.CreateObject` (needs a COM-visible .NET assembly) are your only two options in Classic ASP.

If the .NET assembly/library you want to use is not COM-visible, and you don't have access to source code, you can create a wrapper - your own .NET assembly that is COM-visible, with pass-through methods - you call your assembly from Classic ASP, and your assembly passes required parameters to the library you actually want to use, and returns results of the corresponding methods.

Comment: I though Server.CreateObject could not be used in an Azure Web App. I will try making the COM visible. Thanks

Comment: @CesarDaniel, I am not sure, but if that's the case, you can still go the Web API route, or host your ASP app in Virtual Machine in Azure (which will allow Server.CreateObject within the image).